# Python mock all future usage

Tags: python, mocking

I want to mock an object such that all future usage (through imports) in my module would use my mocked object instead of importing the regular object.

As far as I understand, mocking something in the regular way using `mock` would only modify it in current namespace (or whichever namespace specified)

Instead of iterating over all namespaces using that object, can I automatically mock all of them?

example:

file a.py

```
class A:
  a = 2
```

file b.py

```
from a import A

B = A.a
```

file c.py

```
from a import A
from b import B

#mock A.a to return 4

print(A.a) # prints 4
print(B)
```

Hope it's clear in this minimal example.

Comment: I think your choices are: 1. mock both namespaces `mock.patch('c.A')` and `mock.patch('b.A')`, but you'd have 2 different mock objects. 2. Import `A` from module `b` in module `c`: `from b import A` and `mock.patch('c.A')`. 3. Change your imports from `from` to just `import a` in all other modules and `mock.patch('a.A')`.

Comment: Damn, this is what i feared. I had hoped i could do it without  changing a or b

Comment: You must mock the object you're using. That's why, when you use a lib in your file, you mock the lib imported in file.